# Convert character date into date in R

Tags: r, date, character

this is my data set overview.
I would like to convert the month(format = character) into formate:date in R

I have tried as.Date() `as.Date(df$month, "%Y-%m")` but it fails to convert.
I have used anytime() and as.POSIXct()

The reason I want to convert date is that I need to left_join with other dataset by the variable rime.

```
   crime_type    month       n   rate
   <chr>         <chr>   <int>  <dbl>
 1 Bicycle theft 2017-04    33 NA    
 2 Bicycle theft 2017-05    32  1.03 
 3 Bicycle theft 2017-06    36  0.889
 4 Bicycle theft 2017-07    39  0.923
 5 Bicycle theft 2017-08    52  0.75 
 6 Bicycle theft 2017-09    36  1.44
```

the other dataset is here

```
 ym      unemploy_rate
   <chr>           <dbl>
 1 2017-1            4.6
 2 2017-2            4.6
 3 2017-3            4.5
 4 2017-4            4.4
 5 2017-5            4.4
 6 2017-6            4.3
 7 2017-7            4.3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `paste` with a day and use `as.Date`

```
df$month <- as.Date(paste0(df$month, "-01"), "%Y-%m-%d")
```

---

Or another option is to convert to `yearmon` class and then use `as.Date`

```
library(zoo)
df$month <- as.Date(as.yearmon(df$month))
```

#### Update

If the objective is to left_join with other dataset where the 'ym' column doesn't have the `0` after the `-`, we can insert that instead of doing the format change on the first data

```
df2$ym <- sub("-(\\d)$", "-0\\1", df2$ym)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
I have use `as.yearmon()` to the dataset, while it produce the undesirable result.

I would like to see date as  `2017-01`

Comment: @JamesHuang From your example, your dataset  it is already YYYY-MM class, Not clear why you need to transform to get that again?

Comment: @JamesHuang i updated the post, but your conditions are not clear

Comment: there are in  `YYYY-MM` class but it's not date format.
I would tried it, thank you

Comment: @JamesHuang then in should work because i used `%Y-%m` and then after pasting the day, it is `%Y-%m-%d`

Comment: Thanks, it works perfect! And I am sorry that I could not vote for you because I am not still qulified.